# Turn a webcam off

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv

Currently My Program is able to turn on the `webcam`, but right now I have no idea how to turn the webcam off by code.

Here's the code I use to capture some pictures:

```
private void webcamStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = new Capture();
    image.QueryFrame();
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
}
```

PS: I using emguCV

Comment: cannot work but thank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,not sure may be help you

```
 Camera.Dispose()
```

Comment: well... the code is working but is pause because I code like this

private void webcamStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image.Dispose();
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
        }

anyway Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you

```
image.Close()
```